# Load different viewer profiles from script

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Google cardboard SDK allows us to load any VR viewer profile from a Unity app by scanning a QR code in the settings. I already have different QR codes for different VR headsets and I'd like to load them from script so that users can choose their device from my menu without having to search the right QR code on the Internet and scan it.

I tried to scan and set a custom VR viewer profile which works as expected. I tried to save this profile on the sdcard by serialising the CardboardProfile object from the Cardboard class with something like this:

```
Serialize (file,Cardboard.device.Profile);
```

And then I tried to load this custom profile at the Cardboard initialisation. 
I set the Profile variable to my custom profile in the InitDevice() function in the Cardboard class:

```
device = BaseVRDevice.GetDevice();
device.Profile = GetComponent<ProfileReader>().Load ();
device.Init();
```

where `GetComponent<ProfileReader>().Load ()` returns my custom deserialised CardboardProfile form the Resources folder (where I copy the file with my serialised object from the sdcard). I set all the needed variables to public and tweaked the setters so that I have access to them. The (de)serialise steps work fine. My CardboardProfile C# object is valid and I double checked the values. But the distortion and viewport won't change. It is still set to the default viewer profile.

Any idea of how I can change these VR viewer profile from script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found it. For those who'd like to change the VR viewer profile from script, have a look to the `VRDevice.cs` file and especially to the `UpdateView()` and `UpdateProfile()` functions. 
They load two float arrays through the `GetViewParameters(viewData)` and `GetProfile(profileData)` calls. These arrays (viewData and profileData) can easily be saved, serialised and loaded. Make sure `UpdateScreenData()` is then called to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/issues/131) answer, you can set a default profile in Cardboard.cs

For example:

```
public Uri DefaultDeviceProfile = new Uri("http://google.com/cardboard/cfg?p=ChlVbm9mZmljaWFsIENhcmRib2FyZCBJbmMuEgtVQyAyLjAgUGx1cx2e7yc9JSUGgT0qEAAASEIAAEhCAABIQgAASEJYATUpXA89Ogh7FK4-zcwMP1AAYAM");
```

I got that url by scanning the profile QR code on an Unofficial Cardboard 2.0 plus, `h t t p : / / g o o . g l /NKZrps`, and then typed that after curl to get what the redirect url was:

```
curl g o o . g l /NKZrps
```

Note: stackoverflow doesn't allow url shorteners, so I had to add spaces.

This of course doesn't let you create a menu of choices for the user, but only preset an option if you know that's what the user will be using.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite correct, as it only tells the Unity layer about your loaded profile, but not the C++ layer.  Moreover, setting the profile from script is not meant to be how the SDK is used, since your app is commandeering the  profile, overriding the user's choice made by scanning the QR code.